# Having troubling listing subdirectories recursively in PHP

Tags: php, recursion

I have the following code snippet. I'm trying to list all the files in a directory and make them available for users to download. This script works fine with directories that don't have sub-directories, but if I wanted to get the files in a sub-directory, it doesn't work. It only lists the directory name. I'm not sure why the is_dir is failing on me... I'm a bit baffled on that. I'm sure that there is a better way to list all the files recursively, so I'm open to any suggestions!

```
function getLinks ($folderName, $folderID) {
$fileArray = array();

foreach (new DirectoryIterator(<some base directory> . $folderName) as $file) {
    //if its not "." or ".." continue
    if (!$file->isDot()) {              
            if (is_dir($file)) {                     
                $tempArray = getLinks($file . "/", $folderID);
                array_merge($fileArray, $tempArray);

            } else {
                $fileName = $file->getFilename();                           
             $url = getDownloadLink($folderID, $fileName);
             $fileArray[] = $url;               
            }                       
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP recursive directory path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398147/php-recursive-directory-path)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using DirectoryIterator, you can use [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php), which provides functionality for iterating over a file structure recursively. Example from documentation:

```
$path = realpath('/etc');

$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach($objects as $name => $object){
    echo "$name\n";
}
```

> This prints a list of all files and
>   directories under $path (including
>   $path ifself). If you want to omit
>   directories, remove the
>   RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
>   part.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! I'll modify my code later and give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: Substituted it into my code and it works great. However, the isDot doesn't work anymore. It gives the following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method SplFileInfo::isDot() . Any idea why?

Comment: @thomascirca: You might wanna have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13069918/89771, seems that SPL is 50%+ slower than other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use RecursiveDirectoryIterator, but you might also want to consider using the [Finder](https://github.com/symfony/Finder) component from Symfony2. It allows for easy on the fly filtering (by size, date, ..), including dirs or files, excluding dirs or dot-files, etc. Look at the docblocks inside the [Finder.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Finder/Finder.php) file for instructions.