# php & recursive Iterator : finding a specific file and its path

Tags: php, file, recursion, iterator, sugarcrm

I'm a newbie in SPL and recursiveIterator... So could you help me?

**What I want to achieve :**

I would like to find a file in a folders tree and i would like to obtain its path.

My folder tree could seems to be like this :

```
./ressources
./ressources/Images
./ressources/Images/Image01
./ressources/Images/Image02
./resources/Images/ImagesSub/Image03
./ressources/Docs
./ressources/Docs/Doc01
```

and so on...

I obtain the name of my File with sql query (warning : they never have an extension).
Now, i want to find the file's location by doing a recursive Iterator on './ressources' folder.

Then, when i've found the file, i would like to return the whole link './ressources/Folder/File'.

I've read [Gordon's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398147/php-recursive-directory-path) but it doesn't work, I tried only to echo something, but doesn't display anything.

Here is my code :

```
$doc_id = $bean->id;
$query = "SELECT a.document_revision_id  FROM  documents as a, document_revisions as b ";
$query .= "WHERE a.document_revision_id = b.id AND a.id = '" . $doc_id . "' LIMIT 1";
$results = $bean->db->query($query, true);
$row = $bean->db->fetchByAssoc($results);

$file_id = $row['document_revision_id'];
$ressources = './ressources/';
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($ressources, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_FILENAME), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($iter as $entry) {
    if ($entry->getFilename() === $file_id){
        echo '<script> alert('.$entry->getFilepath().');</script>';
    }
}
```

(i know doing an alert into a echo is bullsh*t, but whith sugar it is quite difficult to display something
**Specifications**

I'm trying to do this in a SugarCrm CE 6.5.2 logic_hook and it's running on archlinux. And my PHP version is 5.4.6

It is really urgent, so I would be reaaaally happy if you could help me!!

Thanks by advance!

**EDIT FROM 12/10/09 2pm:
What is my sugar project and why i can't get the pathname from my database**

I created a custom field in Documents module called folder_name_c. You fill it with the name of the folder (under ressources) where you want to upload your document.

I want to allow the user to move the file uploaded from its ancient folder to new one when i edit the document.

When editing a document, I did a after_retrieve hook to permit the logic_hook to work when editing (before, it was just done for edit view)

So, if i get the $bean->folder_name_c, it pick up the field's content. If i try sql, it will pick the folder_name_c only after i click "save".

So, i don't have any clue to get my old folder_name to create an

```
$old_link = '.ressources/'.$old_folder.'/'.$file_id;
```

I can only create the

```
$new_link = '.ressources/'.$bean->folder_name_c.'/'.$file_id;
```

So, after a long time, i figured out that i could browse my ressources folder and my sub folders to find my file named $file_id and then create the $old_link

FYI, by creating a new custom field under studio in sugar, i gained a lot of time.
I don't want to pass my life on adding a custom_code calling database or else. this is URGENT and recursive iterator seems to be simple and quick.

Comment: why not store the full path of the file in the database?

Comment: @HorusKol i did edit my question to add some information about the project. So i really want to do that by recursive iterator. if you have any clue on what's wrong, i'll take it with lot of joy :)

Comment: I am sorry but I really didn't get the essence of the problem. Could you reduce your question to the important parts?

Comment: as I said first : "I would like to find a file in a folders tree and i would like to obtain its path." i have the name of the file (but there is no extension, so i can't search for '.jpg' (for example) )
So to do this, i need recursive functions or recursive iterator (which seems to be more comfy to code)

Answer (score 1):

There is no method such as `getFilepath` for the `(Recursive)DirectoryIterator`, just use `$entry` itself, when used in a string context it's casted to such one (à la [`__toString`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)):

```
$file_id = 'test';
$ressources = './ressources/';

// [...]

echo '<script>alert('.$entry.');</script>'; // is casted to a string which contains the full path

// results in alerting ./resources/SubFolder/test
```

I tested it with the same structure and without extension.

Comment: thanks @dan-lee, i've find it out before reading your comment :) i'll answer my own question to give the code.. But maybe you could help me with a copy/unlink file..

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found out how to use recursive iterators for my problem!
Here is my code :

```
$ressources = './ressources/';
$directoryIter = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($ressources);
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directoryIter, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$old_path = '';
$new_path = $ressources.$bean->folder_name_c.'/'.$file_id;
chmod($new_path,0777);

foreach ($iter as $entry) {

    if (!$directoryIter->isDot()) {

        if ($entry->getFileName() == $file_id) {
            $old_path = $entry->getPathName();
            chmod($old_path, 0777);
            copy($old_path,$new_path);

         }
    }
}
```

So i succeed to get my file's origin path! :)

But *as always*, **there is a problem**:

I want to cut and paste my file from $old_path to $new_path *(as you can see in my code)*. The copy here works well, but i don't know where i have to unlink() the old_path.. if anyone knows ...
(and if i wrote the copy in the wrong line, just tell me please! :D )

Comment: Use [`rename()`](http://php.net/rename) for that (as moving is nothing different than renaming).

Comment: So many thanks @dan-lee ! Well, as usual Sugar got me into some troubles... : i replaced `copy($old_path,$new_path);` with `rename($old_path,$new_path);` and, well, it works well, when i save a nnew Doc (let's say Doc01), and then edit it few times..But sugar keep the last folder_name (say Folder05) in some memory and when i want to upload a new Doc (called Image01), even if i give another folder name like FolderImg, it renames my new doc into Folder05.. and i don't know how to fix it...