# PHP - Listing all directories and sub-directories recursively in drop down menu

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, recursion, directory, subdirectory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Get all subdirectories of a given directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524151/php-get-all-subdirectories-of-a-given-directory)

I want a drop down menu to show all sub-directories in `./files/$userid/` not just the main folder. For example:    `/files/$userid/folder1/folder2/`

My current code is:

HTML:

```
<select name="myDirs">
<option value=""  selected="selected">Select a folder</option>
```

PHP:

```
if (chdir("./files/" . $userid)) {

       $dirs = glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
       foreach($dirs as $val){
          echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$val."</option>\n";
       }        
        } else {
       echo 'Changing directory failed.';
}
```

Comment: And your question is? Keep in mind that formulating requirements is not a programming question. I suggest you search for your requirements on site first, because listing directories has been asked and answered in various flavors already. [So why not take a place at the bar and order your drink?](http://stackoverflow.com/search)

Comment: You will need to use PHP's native [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) class. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2398163/427992) should help.

Comment: I tried this http://pastebin.com/fpJiiCbZ, but it doesn't work. This is the output I get: http://i.imgur.com/gWt3U.png

Comment: You didn't implement the correct code. Copy and paste the PHP code set out in the above answer and it should work.

Comment: I did, I don't want to get filenames, only folders. What's 'work.txt' in the answer? (Copy pasting the code return empty drop-down)

Comment: So Ok, I did as you told me, with little modifications, and it's working. However I would like to ask a question. Drop down values are being listed, for example /files/14/blabla are being displayed more than once. Why is this? Here's a screenshot to get the idea.. Code: http://pastebin.com/cGKRkJzn Image: http://i.imgur.com/8HY8a.png . Is there a method how to supress the root folder from being shown?

Comment: Inside every directory there are two (pseudo) files called `.` and `..`. If you look carefully, your script is showing them. To omit them, use `!$file->isDot()` in your if statement.

Comment: @Jamie That returns an empty drop box. I did `if($file->isDir() && !$file->isDot() ) { .. }`

Comment: @Jamie Nevermind, used RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) should do the trick. Unfortunately, the documentation is not great, so here is an example:

```
$root = '/etc';

$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD // Ignore "Permission denied"
);

$paths = array($root);
foreach ($iter as $path => $dir) {
    if ($dir->isDir()) {
        $paths[] = $path;
    }
}

print_r($paths);
```

This generates the following output on my computer:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /etc
    [1] => /etc/rc2.d
    [2] => /etc/luarocks
    ...
    [17] => /etc/php5
    [18] => /etc/php5/apache2
    [19] => /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
    [20] => /etc/php5/mods-available
    [21] => /etc/php5/conf.d
    [22] => /etc/php5/cli
    [23] => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
    [24] => /etc/rc4.d
    [25] => /etc/minicom
    [26] => /etc/ufw
    [27] => /etc/ufw/applications.d
    ...
    [391] => /etc/firefox
    [392] => /etc/firefox/pref
    [393] => /etc/cron.d
)
```

Comment: thanks @PleaseStand its work fine, only need one more foreach loop for list view like your output

Comment: Nice one. It would be better if you can illustrate how to filter away hidden folders & their contents (such as `.svn`).

Comment: doesn't work for me... just timeouts even on timeout set to one hour when directory count is only 1000

Answer (score 13):

You can write your own recursive listing of the directories like:

```
function expandDirectories($base_dir) {
      $directories = array();
      foreach(scandir($base_dir) as $file) {
            if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
            $dir = $base_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
            if(is_dir($dir)) {
                $directories []= $dir;
                $directories = array_merge($directories, expandDirectories($dir));
            }
      }
      return $directories;
}

$directories = expandDirectories(dirname(__FILE__));
print_r($directories);
```

Comment: this is a great php solution without using external libraries

Comment: Comparing the accepted answer with this one, terminal: `time php -f test.php`, this one is faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursive glob implementation like in this function:

```
function rglob($pattern='*', $path='', $flags = 0) {
$paths=glob($path.'*', GLOB_MARK|GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT);
$files=glob($path.$pattern, $flags);
foreach ($paths as $path) {
  $files=array_merge($files,rglob($pattern, $path, $flags));
}
return $files;
}
```

Comment: @user183391 that lists files or folders?

Comment: You can use GLOB_ONLYDIR for $flags argument