# RecursiveIteratorIterator return . and .. for each directory

Tags: php

i used `RecursiveIteratorIterator` to get recursive directory lists in Linux but when i try to get directories i have tow version of each directory with . and .. like this :

```
  'dirs' => 
    array (size=13)
      0 => string './..' (length=4)
      1 => string './..' (length=4)
      2 => string './.' (length=3)
      3 => string './.idea/..' (length=10)
      4 => string './.idea/.' (length=9)
      5 => string './.idea/scopes/..' (length=17)
      6 => string './.idea/scopes/.' (length=16)
      7 => string './images/..' (length=11)
      8 => string './images/.' (length=10)
      9 => string './test/..' (length=9)
      10 => string './test/.' (length=8)
      11 => string './test/test2/..' (length=15)
      12 => string './test/test2/.' (length=14)
```

my code is :

```
$files = [ 'files' => [ ], 'dirs' => [ ] ];

  $directories = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.'));
            while ($directories->valid())
            {

                if ($directories->isFile())
                {
                    $files['files'][] = $directories->getPathName();
                } elseif ($directories->isDir())
                {
                    $files['dirs'][] = $directories->getPathName();
                }

                $directories->next();
            }
```

when i use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS` like blow code :

```
        $directories = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
```

i don't have any result.

Comment: Those . and ..  results are virtual nodes, you need to skip them.  try  if($directories->isDot()) continue;  as the first line in your while loop.

Comment: This might help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304935/php-listing-all-directories-and-sub-directories-recursively-in-drop-down-menu a sample using the ::SKIP_DOTS instruction.